# Set up labels and legend using plt.subplots()

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, legend, label

I am using plt.sublot to create a figure with 12 subplots that share the same data so I want to show the labels and legend for one of them. I am accessing and plotting the data from a dictionary that contains pandas dataframes each with 20 columns(labels). Here my code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, sharex=True, sharey=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.06, bottom = 0.1, right = 0.8, top=0.9, 
wspace=0.15, hspace=0.15)
fig.suptitle('HMC Water Balance', fontsize = 20, y= 0.95, x=0.45)

axes[0,0].plot(HMC_hydrographs['outlet'])
axes[0,1].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet00'])
axes[0,2].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet01'])
axes[0,3].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet02'], label = 
'Q_total','Q_reset','Q_river_initial', ...'20th_column_name')
ax = axes[0,3]
ax.legend(loc=0, prop={'size':8})
axes[1,0].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet03'])
ax = axes[1,0]
ax.set_ylabel('Flux (m$^3$/s)', labelpad=10, fontsize = 18)
axes[1,1].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet04'])
axes[1,2].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet05'])
axes[1,3].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet06'])
axes[2,0].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet07'])
axes[2,1].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet08'])
ax = axes[2,1]
ax.set_xlabel('Time (days)', fontsize = 18)
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.1,-0.2)
axes[2,2].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet09'])
axes[2,3].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet10'])
```

I get the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-249-7e4552c68d90>", line 8
axes[0,3].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet02'], label = 
'Q_total','Q_reset','Q_river_initial')
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

For what I understand the label argument takes only one argument but I have more than one label!

Please help me understand how to call the labels so they show like when I plot a single graph like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = HMC_hydrographs['Outlet01'].plot()
```

[Individual plot showing the correct labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBuxF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the reasoning behind it but the way I managed to get the legend to show was to specify the labels directly into the legend argument, not using the 'label' argument. Here is the code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, sharex=True, sharey=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(left = 0.06, bottom = 0.1, right = 0.8, top=0.9, 
wspace=0.15, hspace=0.15)
fig.suptitle('HMC Water Balance', fontsize = 20, y= 0.95, x=0.45)
axes[0,0].plot(HMC_hydrographs['outlet'])
axes[0,1].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet00'])
axes[0,2].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet01'])
axes[0,3].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet02'])
ax = axes[0,3]
ax.legend(hydro_header, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, 
borderaxespad=0.)
axes[1,0].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet03'])
ax = axes[1,0]
ax.set_ylabel('Flux (m$^3$/s)', labelpad=10, fontsize = 18)
axes[1,1].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet04'])
axes[1,2].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet05'])
axes[1,3].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet06'])
axes[2,0].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet07'])
axes[2,1].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet08'])
ax = axes[2,1]
ax.set_xlabel('Time (days)', fontsize = 18)
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(1.1,-0.2)
axes[2,2].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet09'])
axes[2,3].plot(HMC_hydrographs['Outlet10'])
```

hydro_header contains a list with the column names(labels) for my plots that I got by using:

```
hydro_header = list(HMC_hydrographs['outlet'])
```

[Final figure with the subplots and legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMkBR.png)